# What's the benefits of asp.net MVC routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Rather than "/MyController/Index?teamId=3&type=4", MVC routing prefers :"/MyController/3/4". So what's the benefits of doing so? On the contrary, I am suffering many drawbacks of it. For example:

1. Not readable for people.

What's 3 and 4?

2. If I store them somewhere (for test cases, etc), different links may point to same pages.

"Have you tested /MyController/3/4?""no, but I've tested /MyController/Index/3/4""..."

3. Difficult to be analyzed by JavaScript.

I have some js codes to make "current link" black text. For example, if a link on the page (usually a menu item) links to the page itself, the link will be changed to black text. But in this case, the link "/MyController/3/4" on page "/MyController/Index/3/4" cannot be processed properly.

So why should we use MVC routing like that? And how should I overcome the 3rd problem listed above? That's why I'm here :)

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: "MyController/3/4" is not readable (an example for the question, no doubt), but something like `/Team/3/Type/4` is more readable than '/MyController/Index?teamId=3&type4' (opinions may vary...)

Answer (score 1):

1. You would be much better off with routing using actual string names instead of IDs where you can get away with it... such as /Teams/TeamNameOrAbbreviation/TeamType
2. Different links pointing to the same pages stems from the defaults set in the routeconfig. If you do not want this to happen, you can change how you are handling your defaults.
3. You can process the links properly if you use MVC's built in methods to do so. You can resolve URLs using helpers such as @Url.Action() for comparison and usage in js code since it always generates the same one every time.

Comment: Great explanation of the 3rd one! I thought Url.Action() returns a <a href="..."></a>, but in fact it returns just a string like "/controller/action". This makes things much easier. Now my code looks like this : Html.MyLink("sometext", Url.Action("Index", new {teamId=team.Id}), "fa fa-cubes"), and the Url.Action will generate a link exactly the same of current Url in the browser address bar. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued)While the old code looked like this: Html.MyLink("SomeText", "/Area/Controller/Index?teamId=" + team.Id, "fa fa-cubes"), and when the "index" was automatically removed from the browser's address bar, the hard coded link would be different. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Html.ActionLink() generates the full URL with the <a href="... and Url.Action() generates only the URL. Important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

It's not MVC Routing where you got confused. What you need to understand is SEO friendly urls. These url("MyController/3/4") helps search engines to easily find the pages.

Have a look at these links. You'll have a better reason.

[SEO Friendly URL](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/five-steps-to-seo-friendly-site-url-structure/)

[MVC Routing](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573454/Routing-in-MVC)

Comment: I've been working on some enterprise webs in which most of the pages cannot be accessed by search engine, so have never thought of SEO. But your links provide something important. I would try it in the home page because it's exposed to the public. Thanks a lot.